# Javascript search for tag and get it's innerHTML

Tags: javascript, search, tags, match, innerhtml

It's probably something really simple, but I'm just learning.

There's a page with 3 blockquote tags on it, and I'd need to get the innerHTML of the one containing a certain string. I don't know how to search/match a string and get the innerHTML of the tag containing the matched result.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var searchString = 'The stuff in innerHTML';
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('blockquote')
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     if (elements[i].innerHTML.indexOf(searchString) !== -1) {
         alert('Match');
         break;
     }
}
```

:)

Btw there would be a much nicer method if you'd be using [Prorotype JS](http://prototypejs.org/) (which is much better than jQuery btw):

```
var el = $$('blockquote').find(function(el) {
    return el.innerHTML.indexOf('The string you are looking for.') !== -1;
});
```

You could of course also use regular expressions to find the string, which might be more useful (use el.match() for that).

Comment: This will only match the element which's innerHTML is exactly like searchString, and that is not what he wants (why would you search for it then, if you already have the string)?

Comment: You are just returning true/false in the last example :)

Comment: Ehm, no? It should return the matched element. I just tested it ;).

Comment: "which is much better than jQuery btw" ... Don't state it like a fact -- it's not one.

Comment: @watain: oh sorry, the `find` method returns the current element if the function you pass it to returns true. My bad :)

Comment: You should be caching `elements.length`

Answer (score 6):

If you need to search through every `<blockquote>` on the page, try this:

```
function findBlockquoteContainingHtml(matchString) {
    var blockquoteElements = document.getElementsByTagName('BLOCKQUOTE');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < blockquoteElements.length; i++) {
        if (blockquoteElements[i].innerHTML.indexOf(matchString) >= 0) {
            return blockquoteElements[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get this to work (even after replacing the last })

Answer (score 4):

Assign an id to the blockquote elements then you can get the innerHTML like this:

HTML:

```
<blockquote id="bq1">Foo</blockquote>
```

JS:

```
var quote1 = document.getElementById('bq1').innerHTML;
```

Comment: It's not my page, I can't assign an ID, but thanks for the reply anyways! :)

Answer (score 3):

Be careful using `innerHTML` to search for text within a tag, as that may also search for text in attributes or tags as well.

You can find all `blockquote` elements using:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("blockquote")
```

You can then look through their `innerHTML`, but I would recommend instead looking through their `textContent`/`innerText` (sadly, this is not standardized across browser, it seems):

```
for (i in elems) {
  var text = elems[i].textContent || elems[i].innerText;
  if (text.match(/foo/)) {
    alert(elems[i].innerHTML);
  }
}
```